# return' character and new line use with regex java 8

Tags: java, regex

I 'm facing strange behaviour in java 8 regarding the use of (\r?\n) inside a regex to parse text file with IDE eclipse runing under java 8.

see  regex101 test demo https://regex101.com/r/QHSsfQ/4

the regex work fine for java 7 with IDE eclipse .

but with IDE runing in java 8  it dosen't work ( see bellow code )

can someone help how me to solved this?

```
    String REGEX =
          "\\s+NAME.*" + "\\r?\\n"
          + "INFO-\\d{1,2}\\s+(?<name>[$\\w]+).*" + "\\r?\\n"
          + ".*" + "\\r?\\n"
            + ".*VERAT2.*" + "\\r?\\n"
            + "\\s+\\w+\\s+(?<verat2>\\w+).*"  
.......
.......

  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( REGEX ).matcher( data );
          
                        if( matcher.find() )
                        {
                      
    System.out.println("LEVELINFO=DATA=" + matcher.group("name") + " &&NAME=" + matcher.group("name") +" &&VERAT2="+ matcher.group("verat2")+"\n"); 
                        }
                    }
                            sc.close();
```

the sample text file looks like this :

```
DATA              NAME                    MAC1  
INFO-0            EQUIP                   Q10    
 
                  VL      VER     VERAT2     
                          V22     V22
```

thanks

Comment: The line break sequence pattern is `\\R`, replace all ``\\r?\\n`` with ``\\R``

Comment: @WiKtor : I have changed all \\r?\\n with \\R but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative regex:**

```
String regexName = "^DATA\\s+NAME\\s+.*?^\\S+\\s+(?<name>\\S+)";
String regexVerat2 = "\\s+VER\\s+VERAT2\\s+.*?^\\s+\\S+\\s+(?<verat2>\\S+)";
String regex = String.format("%s.*?%s", regexName, regexVerat2);
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(input);
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input =
              "DATA              NAME                                  MAC1  MAC2\n"
            + "INFO-0            EQUIP                                 Q10    Q13\n"
            + " \n"
            + "                  VL                    VER     VERAT2     MAP\n"
            + "                                        V22     V22       SELF100\n"
            + " \n"
            + "                  CMD1 CMD2       CMD3     CMD4     CMD4  \n"
            + "                  NO    44        FAL      BYTE\n";

    String regexName = "^DATA\\s+NAME\\s+.*?^\\S+\\s+(?<name>\\S+)";
    String regexVerat2 = "\\s+VER\\s+VERAT2\\s+.*?^\\s+\\S+\\s+(?<verat2>\\S+)";
    String regex = String.format("%s.*?%s", regexName, regexVerat2);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(input);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group("name"));
        System.out.println("Verat2 : " + matcher.group("verat2"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: EQUIP
Verat2 : V22
```